# HW - Number of subspaces T of a vector space K containing a fixed subspace M.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

> Given a vector space $K$ of dimension $k$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, what is the number of subspaces $T$ of dimension $t<k$ that contain a given subspace $M$ of dimension $m<t$?

This is a homework question, so I'm more looking for a hint than anything else. I conclude that since $K = K' \oplus M$ for some subspace $K'$ of dimension $k-m$, then any subspace $T$ containing $M$ can be written as $T=T' \oplus M$, where $T'$ is a subspace of $K'$ of dimension $t-m$.

The expression matches each $T$ one-to-one with a representative subspace $T'$, so that the answer we're looking for should be $\binom{k-m}{t-m}_q.$ But the answer that we are supposed to reach is $q^{m(k-t)}\binom{k-m}{t-m}_q,$ and I have no idea where to even begin to understand where the factor $q^{m(k-t)}$ comes from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This appears to be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140946/the-number-of-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-forming-direct-sum-with-a-given-subpac?rq=1

Comment: Are you looking at vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or over a finite fild?  If the former, how many planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contain the line $\{(t,t,t) : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$?

Comment: Sorry, it is over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: David, I did see the related page, but the question is precisely where $q^{m(k-t)}$ comes from. He talks about preimages $\pi^{-1}$ of sets (assumingly subspaces) of $K \mod M$ but there is no reason I can think of that, say, a given subspace $T'$ of $K \mod M$ (and hence of dimension $t-m$) is mapped onto by more than one subspace $T$ containing $M$ of dimension $t$ in $K$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "standard" answer $q^{m(k-t)}\binom{k-m}{t-m}_q$ is correct.
This problem is different from that in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140946/the-number-of-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-forming-direct-sum-with-a-given-subpac?rq=1).
I think your answer is correct -- in $\mathbb{F}_q^k$, the number of $t$-dimensional subspaces that contain a fixed $m$-dimensional subspace is exactly $\binom{k-m}{t-m}_q$